# Choppy animation of large image backgrounds

Tags: jquery, image, performance, jquery-animate, css

I am finishing website with large image backgrounds stretched by `background-size:cover`. Please have a look here: http://knihaoplanu.g6.cz

As you probably see, vertical animation is not that smooth. Size of all JPEG images does not exceed 500KB, their dimensions are usually somewhere around 1000x500.

I use very basic code:

```
function SlideShow() {
    $('#wrapper .scroll').bind('click',function(e){

    // SETUP
    e.preventDefault();
        var $anchor = $(this).attr('href');

        // ANIMATION
        $('#wrapper').stop().animate({
            scrollLeft: $($anchor).position().left
        }, 1000);
    });
```

Do you have any ideas for me how to make the animations smoother? I've found some similar topics online but none of them provided very clear answers (at least for me). One of them suggested that the problem lay with `background-size:cover`, however the choppiness remained even without that.

Thank you very much!

## EDIT (solved)

CSS animations are definitely the way - animations got A WAY smoother. I do not want to recode the site as it is very close to the deadline, so I used [jQuery Transit plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/), as Marcus kindly suggested.

Sadly, I'm still not entirely done. When I replace my `scrollLeft` command with `x` (as suggested on plugin's website), my horizontal layout based on percentage kind of melts. :)

Can you guide me how to use scrollLeft AND retain Transit's functionality?

THANK YOU!

Comment: You should look into [animating using CSS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_animations) instead.

Comment: Is it possible to achieve the smoother effect with good old jQuery? I would like to use CSS3 animations as a last resort, as it would mean a lot of recoding ...

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using? You could give [transit](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit) a shot.

Comment: Transit is definitely a way! Would you be so kind to check my edited question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, an awesome [Transit Plugin](http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit/) was the answer! The animations are still a little choppy if you run them slower than 500 seconds (tested on Firefox and Chrome), but that isn't that big of an issue for me.

And about the edit - I forgot to make the `x` parameter negative. :)

Thank you Marcus!